# different version of pascal triangle, list, python

Tags: python, list, pascals-triangle

I am a beginner in python and I have to do a special version of pascal triangle...special in a way that the elements don't add up but they multiply.

***here is the example:*** so the function is defined as *multiplicative_pascal(start: int, height: int) -> List[List[int]]*

for `start = 2` and `height = 5` the function should return

```
[[2 ], [2, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 8, 8, 2], [2, 16, 64, 16, 2]]
```

***My thought process and code***

First I tried to make normal pascal triangle and then I thought I will just substitute the + with * and 1(the normal starting point for pascal triangle) with the variable start

```
def multiplicative_pascal(start: int, height: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    Pascal_list =[[start]]   #FIrst entry Defined to start 
    for i in range(start, height+1): 
        temp_list =[]
        for j in range(i+1):  #+1 As we are considering last element
            if(j==0):#First Element = start
                temp_list.append(start)
                continue
            elif(j == i):#Last Element = start
                temp_list.append(start)
                continue
            else:
                temp_list.append(Pascal_list[i-1][j]+Pascal_list[i-1][j-1]) # Addition of Upper Two Elements
        Pascal_list.append(temp_list)
    return Pascal_list 
print(multiplicative_pascal(1, 5))
```

for this function it printed what it should here is the result

[[1 ], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]]

but when I try to change from *print(multiplicative_pascal(1, 5))* to *print(multiplicative_pascal(2, 5))* it gives me this error and I am not sure why [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS77l.png) 
if you don't wan't to go to external link :

> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dalšie štúdium!!\MUNI\Informatika\ucenie na
>   semestralny test.py", line 108, in 
>       print(multiplicative_pascal(2, 5))   File "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dalšie štúdium!!\MUNI\Informatika\ucenie na
>   semestralny test.py", line 105, in multiplicative_pascal
>       temp_list.append(Pascal_list[i-1][j]+Pascal_list[i-1][j-1]) # Addition of Upper Two Elements IndexError: list index out of range

*

could someone please help me with this error? or how would you try to solve this problem? maybe my whole thought process is wrong...

Comment: Show requirements, code, output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Comment: `Pascal_list[i-1]`. Note `for i in range(start, height+1): `, so on the first pass it becomes `Pascal_list[start - 1]`.  At first, there is only one element in that list: `Pascal_list =[[start]]`, so using a `start` value of  `2` results in you trying to access one element beyond the size of that list.

Comment: Thank you for your commend, I think I understand, but I seem not to be able to fix it. 
so essentially if my start value > 1 the Pascal_list[start - 1]....the -1 is not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will help you:

```
def multiplicative_pascal(start: int, height: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    if height < 1:
        return []
    result = row = [start]
    for _ in range(height - 1):
        row = [start] + [(a * b) for a, b in zip(row, row[1:])] + [start]
        result.append(row)
    return result

>>> multiplicative_pascal(1, 5)
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]  # 1 * 1 is always 1...

>>> multiplicative_pascal(2, 5)
[[2], [2, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 8, 8, 2], [2, 16, 64, 16, 2]]
```